# Pluggable Conventions in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am following [EF Feature CTP5: Pluggable Conventions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/10/ef-feature-ctp5-pluggable-conventions.aspx) to create custom pluggable convention (in this particular case to change the precision of all decimal fields).

Looks like in the latest release of EF the `Add` method on `ConventionsConfiguraions` is also "internal'. How do i add custom Pluggable Conventions now?

Comment: I wrote an interim solution for this feature.  It is available on NuGet http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature has been removed in EF 4.1 and a possible implementation postponed to a later release:

> Code First customizable (pluggable)
>   conventions are not supported.
>   Removing the default Code First
>   conventions is supported.

Quote from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696165%28v=VS.103%29.aspx

And:

> **Removal of Code First Pluggable Conventions.** Pluggable Conventions
>   were previewed in Feature CTP5 but
>   were not at go-live quality for this
>   release. This release still supports
>   the removal of default conventions.

Quote from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx

That's why `Add` doesn't exist anymore as a public method of `ConventionsConfiguration`, only `Remove` is still available.

Comment: that's sad. now i have to manually set precision for 100+ fields until this feature is implemented. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Vitalik: Yes, that's tedious. I don't know a solution. But imo the point is interesting enough to ask this as a separate question to get attention by more readers. Would interest me too if there is another way.

Answer (score 2):

I have blogged about an alternative way of defining conventions here: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/04/conventions-in-entity-framework-41.html